# Disable a webpage in a website

Tags: html, jsp, web

I am trying to find a way to disable a webpage from a website, I can't entirely delete the page as I want it to be accessable at one part of the website but not the other.

Basiaclly, for this website a user can choose between two locations at the homepage, one functionality of the website is not ecessary for one location but is needed for the other.

Now, I know I can add some logic to my header file, which will remove the page from the drop-down GUI. but then if users have the URL to the page, they can still access it. is there a way to solve this.

I seem to find this tag used for these situations

```
<sec: authorize access="rules">
```

but I'm not sure how to use it!

Comment: Can you add some logic to your controller to only show the page when the session is in a certain state? Or use role based security. I think we need more information about your problem, and this 'tag' you have found

Comment: Thats the tag, I don't know why it didn't appear in the question!
 <sec: authorize access="rules"> 

Basically, I have this website where you can choose two locations at the home page, some functioality of the website is not eccessary for one of the locations, and I would like to disable it. But I can't delete the page as it is neccessary for the other location.

Comment: Where did you find this tag? I guess there should be some documentation on the web page where you found it.

Comment: yeah, its a Spring framework thing. But my question is how do developers normally go around disabling web pages in such situations?

Comment: Have you implemented authentication? If the users are allowed to choose either location from the homepage, then it wouldn't matter if they have the URL to the page? If you have implemented authentication then you can use the `sec:authorize` tag to authorise the page for a given user

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to restrict access to a page based on the user trying to access it. Using spring security you can limit access to a page based on user roles. The following will only allow users with role `ROLE_ADMIN` to access the admin page.

```
<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.htm" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <security:form-login 
        login-page="/login.htm"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.htm?error=true"
        default-target-url="/"/>
    <security:logout
        invalidate-session="true"
        logout-success-url="/login.htm"
        logout-url="/logout.htm"/>
</security:http>
```

To authorize within a JSP you can use the `<sec:authorize>` tag:

```
<div>
    <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
        You are an ADMIN!!!!
    </sec:authorize>
</div>
```